# Search an Unsorted List

Tags: list, object, search

I have an unsorted list of objects. Each object contains a unique search key. Here's some sample code:

```
import java.util.*;

class Dog {
    private final String nameKey;
    private final String owner;
    private final int age;
    private final int weight;

    Dog(String n, String o, int a, int w) {
        nameKey = n;
        owner = o;
        age = a;
        weight = w;
    }   
    String getName() {
        return nameKey;
    }
    String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
        int getWeight() {
    return weight;
    }    
}

public class SearchThoughList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        String searchString;

        dogList.add(new Dog("squire", "tom:", 10, 40));  
        dogList.add(new Dog("lucy","tom", 5, 37));
        dogList.add(new Dog("gretta", "bob", 12, 22));
        dogList.add(new Dog("lassie", "timmy", 7, 55));
        dogList.add(new Dog("bailey", "bob", 5, 100));

        searchString = "lassie";

        // Here's where I need help
        // i = SomeClass.searchMethod(dogList, searchString);
        //

        System.out.println(searchString+" is at index: "+i);

    }    
}
```

**Question 1:**
What's a good way to search the list and find the element whose key is equal to the search value? Obviously, since the list is unsorted, I'll need to iterate through the whole thing until finding the key. I could write the code to do that. But, being new to Java and OOP, I'm wondering if there already exists a class/method that does this -- more in the spirit of the OOP paradigm.

**Question 2:**
Suppose the list is sorted, does there exist a better structure to use than the ArrayList? Then I assume there exists a class/method that can use a binary search?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What I would use is an enhanced for-loop. Which is used the following way:

```
for(Dog e : dogList){
    //Do stuff with e (which is a dog object)
}
```

You can also use the Iterator pattern, an iterator is an object that loops over a list for you. You can find more on it on the site of oracle:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

When you want to use binary search, an Array List is perfectly fine.

Comment: Using this structure I'd have to use `dogList.indexOf(e)` to get the index of the matching element when I find it. Given that, wouldn't it be better to step through the list with `for (int i=0; i<dogList.size(); i++) {`? That way I already have the index when I find the match.

Comment: Yeah, sorry that is better indeed. I didn't realize you needed the index, I though you needed the object only.